# IOException parsing XML document from class path resource - HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init()

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am building a simple Spring MVC Maven built java WAR application. My Maven project cleans and builds successfully and deploys to the server with no errors using the eclipse tomcat plugin. However, when I try to run the application Servlet, I get the following exception :

```
    Aug 23, 2013 2:35:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'FileWatcher': initialization started
Aug 23, 2013 2:35:29 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'FileWatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Aug 23 14:35:29 BST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 23, 2013 2:35:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml]
Aug 23, 2013 2:35:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 33 more
```

My project configuration is as follows :

*web.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>FileWatcher</display-name>

    <description>File Watcher</description>


    <!-- To load multiple context files here just put a space between your files 
        listed, like here http://blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring/ -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileWatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/file-watcher.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileWatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FileWatcher/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/file-watcher.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

*pom.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="FileWatcher" class="com.test.FileWatcher" init-method="initialize" />

</beans>
```

And my Java class looks as follows :

```
 public class FileWatcher {
    ....
    }
```

I am new to using this system so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong, can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: do you have `spring/file-watcher.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes` ?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a WEB-INF/classes folder, should I create one?

EDIT : 
Scratch that, I've checked the target directory, and theres a WEB-INF/classes directory there that contains a file-watcher.xml file. Does it need to be in a spring directory?

Comment: Your path should be matched to your context param  in web.xml file    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/file-watcher.xml</param-value>

Comment: Thanks, I've done this but I still have the error...Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Create the spring named folder under  WEB-INF.

Create the file-watcher.xml file inside the spring folder.

After that your path will be

yourproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\file-watcher.xml

Paste the below XML content to file-watcher.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

     <bean id="FileWatcher" class="com.test.FileWatcher" init-method="initialize" />

   </beans>
```

Then run your server. It will work.

Comment: Hi there,
Thanks for the help. I'm still getting the Error code 500. Any idea why the spring folder isn't generated automatically? I have to keep adding it to the target/WEB-INF directory after every maven clean install

Comment: Please place like this user-management\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\file-watcher.xml.  user-management is my project root path. Don't place any resources with in target folder that will destroyed if you run mvn clean.

Comment: That works fine, but still an error code 500.
The folder ends up here : 
...\FileSystem\target\watchFileSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\spring

Comment: Thats okay maven will copy the resources and other stuff to target folder. Are you getting any exception. if yes post here

Comment: Yep, here is a link to the full exception on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/gMEZPZmp

Comment: Still you not created file like this yourproject\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\file-watcher.xml.  Its looking for file-watcher.xml file but file is not present.

Comment: The following image shows my project directory structure post building : 
http://i.imgur.com/sEi6AyN.jpg

Comment: edited the main answer please follow. i removed the classes from the path.

Comment: Tried this and still no solution. could anything be wrong with the rest of my configuration?
Does the webapp folder need to be on the classpath? (my src folder is already on the classpath)

Comment: Its path problem I am sure about it. see the IOException and nested exception is FileNotFoundException ....... IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/file-watcher.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)

Comment: I believe you but unfortunately I can't see a single problem with my path, from this image, can you see any problems I can't see?
http://i.imgur.com/sEi6AyN.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36119/discussion-between-prabhakaran-and-matt-mcgrath)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion i might give you is for you check the location of your **file-watcher.xml**

If you are using Maven you might want to consider putting your **file-watcher.xml** inside the **resources** folder.

And in your **web.xml** file kindly declare your  tag as shown below:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:file-watcher.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

NB: Make sure that **src/main/java/resources** is on your classpath and bear in mind that in [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), the standard directory for resources is **src/main/resources**, so I suggest you put this file there.